# uploading csv with pandas in was cloud9

Tags: python, pandas, csv, error-handling

I have downloaded and installed pandas in cloud9, however when I 
use

```
'''
pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")

'''
```

I keep getting this error message

```
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ec2-user/environment/lab_5.py", line 4, in <module>
pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")

File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-     packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)

File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

 File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

 File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Housing.csv' does not exist: b'Housing.csv'

'''
```

I have my housing.csv in the same folder as lab_5.py. Can anyone please explain how upload a csv to cloud9 so that it can be read properly.

Comment: Based on the error, it seems that the `csv` file is not present. Also, the file name that you are running seems to be `lab_5.py` and not `lab.py`.

Comment: yes, I know it saying the csv file isn't present, but I have it in the folder. cloud9 just isn't picking it up for some reason ?

Comment: Did you try giving absolute path like /home/ec2-user/environment/Housing.csv?

Answer (score 0):

When it says in your output, second paragraph:

```
'''
File "/home/ec2-user/environment/lab_5.py", line 4, in <module>
pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")
'''
```

It gives you your current working directory in Cloud9:

```
/home/ec2-user/environment/lab_5.py
```

If your csv is in the same folder as your lab_5.py, then you should be able to replace that with your Housing.csv like so and plug it into your pandas.read_csv():

```
pd.read_csv("/home/ec2-user/environment/Housing.csv")
```

I was able to get it to work when I did that.

Also, at the top of your Cloud9 file explorer, it should say your directory. The one in the screenshot is "/home/ec2-user/environment", but another common one is "/home/ubuntu/environment".

[Your Cloud9 directory: This one is "/home/ec2-user/environment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P79l1.png)